# None specific url api call

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

`http://example.co/?method=get&search=hours&type=place&place_id=1&format=json` is my url api call. It returns a file with no extension and the format is in a json format 
Ex:

```
   ` [
{
"hours":
{
    "monday":
    {
        "open_time":"11:00:00",
        "close_time":"22:00:00"
    },
    "tuesday":
    {
        "open_time":"11:00:00",
        "close_time":"22:00:00"
    },
    "wednesday":
    {
        "open_time":"11:00:00",
        "close_time":"22:00:00"
    },
    "thursday":
    {
        "open_time":"11:00:00",
        "close_time":"22:00:00"
    },
    "friday":
    {
        "open_time":"11:00:00",
        "close_time":"23:00:00"
    },
    "saturday":
    {
        "open_time":"11:00:00",
        "close_time":"23:00:00"
},
"sunday":
{
    "open_time":"11:00:00",
    "close_time":"21:00:00"
}
}
}
```

]`

Everytime i try using either .getJSON or .ajax it won't work. 
My Questions are 
1. What is another type of way to retrieve data from a server using an url within an api call

2.Would xmlHTTPRequest() work just as good as .getJSON or .ajax and if so what would the implementation of it be?

Comment: .ajax and .getJSON using XmlHTTTPRequest. Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: no i haven't seen any errors. I might have the implementation wrong. What's a good example for them?

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? Can you explain?

Comment: Are you waiting for the callback to invoke before trying to access the data? Remember that fetching from the internet like this is **asynchronous**

Comment: Please show us your ACTUAL code so we can offer opinions on what you're doing wrong.  Are you aware of [same-origin restrictions](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FSame_origin_policy_for_JavaScript&ei=yoJQU4u4KcuRyATd-YCwDA&usg=AFQjCNGJ1-YtDsCj5BCtdLq1wRuON-if6A&sig2=5fWp7_StFVJUHH3aQRFeBw&bvm=bv.65058239,d.aWw)?

Comment: If you intend to use this from places where you will fail the same origin policy, you'll also need to either send _CORS_ headers from your server, add a _JSONP_ version, or both.

Comment: this is my actual code using ajax and the api url 
$.ajax(
 { 
  type: 'GET', 
  url: 'http://example.co/?method=get&search=operating_hours&type=place&place_id=1&format=json.json', 
  data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  async: false,
  success: function (data) 
  { }
});

Answer (score 0):

If you're not getting any console errors, you may be receiving the data fine, but not dealing with it asynchronously. It should look something like this:

```
// make the ajax call
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'json',
  // the base url
  url: 'http://example.co/',
  // your query string params get passed as an object
  data: {
    'method': 'get',
    'search': 'hours',
    'type': 'place',
    'place_id': '1',
    'format': 'json'
  },
  success: function(response) {
    // parse the JSON into a javascript object
    var data_obj = JSON.parse(response)
    // now that we have the data, use it
    doSomething(data_obj);
  }
});

// this function gets called by the ajax success callback
function doSomething(data) {
  // do something with your data
}
```

Comment: if you were to take out the information in data and place it into .ajax forms we would have the same code that still doesn't work

Comment: where are you getting the `.json%27` at the end of your url? there shouldn't be a file extension at the end of your query string. And yes, the query params should go under `data:` in the ajax call, not under `url:`

Comment: there is no file extension after my url